# $multiply providing null when in $project field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb and having an issue with my $mutiply, it is producing null when i'm trying to multiply the number of staff with a random figure I made up of '100,000' to be the average wage, which I have just labeled 'Wages'.

I have tried splitting my $project into a 2 stage $project, I have tried adding fields to my $project, moving the order around and it is still producing null.

```
db.HomeWork.aggregate([
{
    $match:{
      category_code:"music_video",
      number_of_staff:{$gte:100}}},
{
        $group:{
          _id: "$business_name"
      }
},
{
  $project:{
    _id:1,
    number_of_staff:1,
    Wages:{
      $multiply:["$number_of_staff",100000]
    }
  }
}
]).pretty()
```

Everything else except for the 'Wages' is fine, but Wages is producing null, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is Data-Type of $number_of_staff?

Comment: $number_of_staff is an Int32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are new in MongoDB, understand aggregate stage of mongoDB properly.. and this is same as what you are trying to do with your data. Since, I have not data of yours I set one example for you. and gives you understanding of stages in aggregation.

**consider this kind of data.**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5db368e9d130deb5c19f35c8"),
    "role" : "cus",
    "created" : 1
 }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5db36913d130deb5c19f35c9"),
    "role" : "cus",
    "created" : 1
 }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5db36926d130deb5c19f35ca"),
    "role" : "support",
    "created" : 5
 }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5db36929d130deb5c19f35cb"),
    "role" : "support",
    "created" : 5
 }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5db37bcfd130deb5c19f35cc"),
    "role" : "support",
    "created" : 5
 }
```

and then **First stage is $match** in aggregate.

```
db.counts.aggregate([ { $match: { created: {$gte:1} } } ])
```

this stage passes all data of created >=1 to next stage, which is $group stage. and result of $match stage is.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5db368e9d130deb5c19f35c8"), "role" : "cus", "created" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5db36913d130deb5c19f35c9"), "role" : "cus", "created" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5db36926d130deb5c19f35ca"), "role" : "support", "created" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5db36929d130deb5c19f35cb"), "role" : "support", "created" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5db37bcfd130deb5c19f35cc"), "role" : "support", "created" : 5 }
```

and then **second stage $group** receives this data. and stage is ...

```
db.counts.aggregate([{ $match: { created: { $gte:1 }} },{ $group: { _id: "$role", count: {$sum:1} } }])
```

above stage filters data group by role and counts numbers of data. and give results given below...

```
{ "_id" : "support", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "cus", "count" : 2 }
```

so, now next stage $project receives only above group stage results. and **$project stage is**

```
db.counts.aggregate([{ $match: { created: { $gte:1 }} },{ $group: { _id: "$role", count: {$sum:1} } },{ $project:{ Multi : { $multiply: [ "$count", 100000 ] }} }])
```

and final stage gives results ...

```
{ "_id" : "support", "Multi" : 300000 }
{ "_id" : "cus", "Multi" : 200000 }
```

**Now, consider your problem**, in your $group stage your are returning only _id field type to $projection stage. and solution of this is...

```
db.counts.aggregate([{ $match: { created: { $gte:1 }} },{ $group: { _id:{Role: "$role",Created: "$created"} } },{ $project:{ Multi : { $multiply: [ "$_id.Created", 100000 ] }} }])
```